# Is there a ArcGIS python script development API?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I am working on a GIS project that supports ArcGIS 9.3 and 10.0 and looking through existing code it looks like the main interface library is `arcgisscripting`.  However, a google search of "arcgisscripting API" or any other variant I can think of only turns up blog posts, forum threads, or broken links.

Is there a core API or reference for `arcgisscripting` or writing Python scripts for ArcGIS?  Am I doing it wrong and need to try something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 9.3 you can use the following diagram:
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=979&pid=977&topicname=Geoprocessor_programming_model

In 10 they switched to using arcpy:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_ArcPy/000v000000v7000000/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

As of ArcGIS 10 its called [arcpy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000001000000.htm).  Keep in mind, you can also call all of the tools found in the [Geoprocessing Tool Reference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_geoprocessing_tool_references/002t0000000z000000/).